# I never made it past Carnival Night Zone

Tags: sonic-3-and-knuckles, sonic-3

Ever since Sonic 3 came out, I never made it past Carnival Night Zone. I'm not sure which act, but I always got trapped at some point and would have to reset the game. I don't think it was a glitch, I just got stuck at some point. It happened back in the day on the Genesis console and even now when I attempt the game using an emulator.

Did this happen to anyone else? I'm a pretty capable gamer, but I never could get past this one part. It seemed that all paths led to this little trap room and there was no way out.

How do I get out?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I think you're talking about the room with the red-and-white diamond barrel in Act 2 where you have to get the barrel low enough in order to progress to the next area. What I thought you needed to do was to jump up and down and time it properly in order to push the barrel down low enough.

***This is the wrong method!***

What you need to do is merely alternate pressing up and down on the directional pad in order to get the barrel to move, no jumping required. You can see a youtube video of this process here:

Do not feel alone! Pretty much everyone I talked to made this mistake as a young gamer. I never completed it either. I did get past the barrel twice I think, but by then I'd come so close to the 10 minute mark that I ran out of time before the end of the level. I didn't find out how to do this until talking with some friends a couple years ago. The answer eluded me for well over 10 years.

Comment: Wow, I never realized there was a legitimate way to get through that part. As a young gamer, however, I proved quite resourceful and got past that part by using the bubble power up and a turbo-enabled controller to crash down on the barrel repeatedly until it got low enough for me to pass (and that's why I could never finish the game as Tails).

Comment: @Aubergine: Ah ha, nice! I never had a turbo controller though, unfortunately. :( And no problem Ronnie! I've talked to so many people who were stuck there. I was so relieved when I found out the answer.

Comment: Oh god I did this so many times until I figured it out.

Comment: Interesting... Somehow I knew about Up/Down to move the barrels. Not sure why (maybe experimenting, maybe reading the manual or some game magazine). So, I never had problems. But TODAY, after reading this question, I realize this has been a very bad game design mistake from the developers, as it adds a new mechanic that is kinda obscure and thus many players don't discover it. That's a pity, as the next zone (Ice Cap) is one of the most beautiful and with an excellent music.

Comment: Rumor has it that Sega's tips hotline had a prerecorded message stating how to get through the barrel problem, it was such a common roadblock.

Comment: It was so terrible, the barrel was actually removed in some later versions of Sonic 3 released in compilation packs and Sonic Jam.

Comment: @Rohaq - That just takes all the fun out of it!

Comment: Well you would say that, @Robotnik!